# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with android annotations for classes with underscore/derived classes

Tags: export, android-annotations

I'm using android annotations and I can compile my project properly and deploy it into my phone from eclipse. However, when I export the app, it gives me a black screen and an this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.tennis-net.android.util.TennisNetApplication_: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tennis-net.android.util.TennisNetApplication_
```

On my other machine, I can export it and it works fine. Anyone ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to Eclipse messing up the build on one of the machines.

Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it entirely?

Worst case, you might even want to try to create a new workspace and then import your existing project folder as "Existing Android Application".

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution, it's because sometimes Eclipse corrupts it, it seems. In your Eclipse, you have to go to Project --> Properties --> Java Compiler --> Annotation Processing and then untick the box, wait until the project is built again and then tick it again and wait until the project is built again.

Then if it still doesn't work, try deplyoing the project in between or restart Eclipse.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me.  The generated files are there though.